# ActionScript 2: Is it possible to test is the mouse is pressed without setting up an event?

Tags: flash, mouse, actionscript-2

Is it possible to read the mouse key, like you do with Key.isDown(), ie. without setting up an unPress event/callback?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is the code in as2:

> this.onMouseDown = function() {
>
> trace("mouseDown");
>
> }